Who was the messenger in Obadiah 1:1?
I know there are several different views on who might be this messenger spoken in Obadiah 1:1

“The vision of Obadiah. Thus says the Lord God concerning Edom: We
have heard a report from the Lord, and a messenger has been sent among
the nations: “Rise up! Let us rise against her for battle!””

With the little information we have it’s difficult to navigate through passages like this. Some say the messenger is some person sent by God, others say it’s a divine messenger appointed by God. This view is taken from scriptures like Psalm 82 where it states that there are other Elohim (gods) that are placed over the nations and who judge the nations which they are placed over.
This is the view I’m leaning towards because it’s has the most scripture to back it up and if God has divine beings placed over nations it would only makes sense that the messenger that is supposed to judge Edom is one of the divine messengers placed by God.
Another hint we see is when it says “Let us rise against her for battle” similar language is used in Genesis 1:26 “let us make man in our image” when God is referring to the divine counsel, could the same “us” the divine counsel be who are being addressed here in Obadiah 1:1?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

We've got to take care to exegete the text and avoid shoehorning interpretations from one passage into another. Some have read Psalm 82 as affirming a host of powerful divine beings - others read it as actively combating that idea and demonstrating YHWH's pre-eminence. Indeed, even Obadiah would appear to go against this idea - if there are true gods over each nation, why does YHWH consistently overstep to judge them all? Edom, Egypt, Babylon, Assyria, Moab, Philistia, Ammon, Tyre, Sidon... it would appear that the remit of YHWH's judgement is all nations.

Tsiyr in Hebrew can mean envoy. Therefore, the envoy is a messenger from a government. Messenger in English causes confusion. Moreover, This text has nothing to do with Gen. 1 and I find it a stretch to see a consultation due to the Hebrew nasah when Gen 1:27 explains 1:26. It appears some other idea is at work in that statement.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is less complicated and obscure that the OP suggests.  There are two matters raised by the OP:
"We"
The plural pronoun is simply the prophet, Obadiah, speaking on behalf of himself and others who have thus heard.  As the Pulpit commentary expresses it:

We have heard. "We" - I myself and other prophets; or the Judaeans,
the prophet identifying himself with his countrymen.

The Cambridge commentary is similar:

We have heard This has been taken to mean, “I, and other prophets of my own or earlier times,” or “I, and my countrymen,” implying, in
this latter case, “that the tidings were of the greatest interest to
Israel, and would afford it consolation.”

"Messenger"
The messenger here is simply that - a messenger sent among the nations to gather various nations into a coalition against Edom = "her".  The time for Edom's destruction had arrived and God was rousing the nations to mete out that final judgement.
